# Django 1.11.7: How do I call a Class method in Views?

Tags: python, django, class

In my models.py I have a Class (Paths) with a method, **validate_time** that tries to access two fields of the Paths model (time_start, time_end):

```
class Paths(m.Model):

  time_start: m.TimeField()
  time_end: m.TimeField() 

  def validate_time(self):
     start = self.time_start
     end = self.time_end
     print start #print start to test it out
     #...some function that returns True or False
```

I call **validate_time** in my views.py:

```
from .models import Paths

def paths_data(request):
  ps = Paths()
  valid_times = ps.validate_time()
  if valid_times == False:
     ....
```

I see the method, validate_time, is hit because I see the print statement

But it appears the print out says: *None*

But **time_start** and **time_end** have already been saved to the model as strings. How can I get them as their string value in **validate_time**?

Comment: Why are you trying to validate an empty Paths object?

Answer (score 0):

I think self.time_start might not have been set as ps is an empty Path object initialized by 'ps = Paths()' and time_start does not have a default value.
If you are looking for a saved instance, you need to query database for it first with something like Paths.objects.get(your_key=your_value). More details on queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score -1):

You can use either @`classmethod` or @`staticmethod` decorator for `validate_time`